# Does millis include time used for getMore operations?

Tags: c#, mongodb, query-optimization

I am running queries on a MongoDB database using the C# driver and .NET Core. When I run my program using `dotnet run -c Release` it takes 32317 ms. However the mongo profiler shows `millis: 130`.

I measure time by using stopwatch in C#:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
List<MyDocument> trs = query.ToList();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"The query took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
```

The query looks like this:

```
db.collection.find({
    "id_test": {
        $in: [
            //some object ids
        ]
    },
    "start": {
        $gte: ISODate(..),
        $lte: ISODate(..)
    },
    state: { $in: ["OK"] },
})
.limit(10000)
```

This is the profiler output:

```
{
  "op": "query",
  "ns": "DB.Collection",
  "command": {
    "find": "Collection",
    "filter": {
      "id_test": {
        "$in": [
          "607585f53b2c57a8f6bf53a2",
          "607585f53b2c57a8f6bf53a8",
          "607585f53b2c57a8f6bf53a5",
          ...
        ]
      },
      "start": {
        "$gte": "2018-05-31T22:00:00.000Z",
        "$lte": "2018-06-30T22:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "state": {
        "$in": [
          "OK"
        ]
      }
    },
    "limit": 10000,
    "comment": "Test02",
    "$db": "DB",
    "lsid": {
      "id": "UUID(\"3320029f-d673-4ae7-b010-559a934745cf\")"
    },
    "$clusterTime": {
      "clusterTime": "Timestamp(1622456713, 1)",
      "signature": {
        "hash": "UUID(\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000000000000\")",
        "keyId": "0"
      }
    }
  },
  "cursorid": "8344635541753646097",
  "keysExamined": 101,
  "docsExamined": 101,
  "fromMultiPlanner": true,
  "numYield": 8,
  "nreturned": 101,
  "queryHash": "BE8D1357",
  "planCacheKey": "5DD51B32",
  "locks": {
    "ParallelBatchWriterMode": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": "1"
      }
    },
    "ReplicationStateTransition": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "w": "10"
      }
    },
    "Global": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": "10"
      }
    },
    "Database": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": "9"
      }
    },
    "Collection": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": "9"
      }
    },
    "Mutex": {
      "acquireCount": {
        "r": "1"
      }
    }
  },
  "flowControl": {},
  "storage": {
    "data": {
      "bytesRead": "33649109",
      "timeReadingMicros": "74017"
    }
  },
  "responseLength": 5407428,
  "protocol": "op_msg",
  "millis": 130,
  "planSummary": "IXSCAN { state: 1, start: 1 }",
  "execStats": {
    "stage": "LIMIT",
    "nReturned": 101,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 9,
    "works": 101,
    "advanced": 101,
    "needTime": 0,
    "needYield": 0,
    "saveState": 9,
    "restoreState": 8,
    "isEOF": 0,
    "limitAmount": 10000,
    "inputStage": {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "filter": {
        "id_test": {
          "$in": [
            "607585f53b2c57a8f6bf53a2",
            "607585f53b2c57a8f6bf53a3",
            "607585f53b2c57a8f6bf53a4",
            ...
          ]
        }
      },
      "nReturned": 101,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 9,
      "works": 101,
      "advanced": 101,
      "needTime": 0,
      "needYield": 0,
      "saveState": 9,
      "restoreState": 8,
      "isEOF": 0,
      "docsExamined": 101,
      "alreadyHasObj": 0,
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "nReturned": 101,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
        "works": 101,
        "advanced": 101,
        "needTime": 0,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 9,
        "restoreState": 8,
        "isEOF": 0,
        "keyPattern": {
          "state": 1,
          "start": 1
        },
        "indexName": "state_start",
        "isMultiKey": false,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "state": [],
          "start": []
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": 2,
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "state": [
            "[\"OK\", \"OK\"]"
          ],
          "start": [
            "[new Date(1527804000000), new Date(1530396000000)]"
          ]
        },
        "keysExamined": 101,
        "seeks": 1,
        "dupsTested": 0,
        "dupsDropped": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "ts": "2021-05-31T10:25:17.637Z",
  "client": "127.0.0.1",
  "allUsers": [],
  "user": ""
}
```

As you can see I want this query to return `10000` documents and it is properly using the index. Using `trs.Count` also shows that it has `10000` items. Because of `nreturned: 101`, I think that mongodb uses `getMore` on the cursor to get more documents. But does `millis` include the time used for `getMore`-operations? If not, how could I get the execution time then to see if the query really took 32317 ms, or if its my program that causes this?

**Edit:**
I tried the same using python with pymongo. It takes the same amount of time. Supposing that `cursorid` is the same for all operations of a query I tried to calculate the sum of `millis` of the operation types `query` and `getmore` that have the same `cursorid`:

```
db.system.profile.aggregate([
    { $match: { "cursorid": NumberLong("...") } },
    { $group: { _id: null, millisSum: { $sum: "$millis" }, nreturnedSum: { $sum: "$nreturned" } } }
])
```

Output:

```
{
  "_id": null,
  "millisSum": 1228,
  "nreturnedSum": 10000
}
```

Which gives the correct sum of returned documents, so I think the time should be correct too.

Comment: _"system.profile.millis

    The time in milliseconds from the perspective of the mongod from the beginning of the operation to the end of the operation."_ https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/#mongodb-data-system.profile.millis

Comment: ^^ So, I would conclude, .Net itself or the C# Mongoclient do add a massive overhead?

Comment: Did you experimant with smaller resultsets?

Comment: @Fildor Thank you, yes but I am not sure whether `getmore` is a separate operation. I guess in this case `millis` would not include the time needed for this. Also I'm trying to understand if it is some overhead caused by .NET or the C# driver

Comment: Yes, I tried limiting results to 1000, that took 4229 ms and 3221 ms, with `millis` still ~ 130 ms.

Comment: Mhm, that would support your suspicion, that stopwatch measures whole roundtrip, while in the profiler it just gives you measurement for one "chunk". But I am not that familiar with the profiler to say for sure.

Comment: what would happen if you set the `batchSize` of the find operation in c# to 10000? afaik, the millis does not include the time it took for the mongo driver to download the bson data and deserialize them in to .net pocos. does your app really need to download all 10,000 matches? i would never display more than 100 items for the user in one page/view. if it's needed for some reporting/calculations, delegate that to the mongo server and download only the final result.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ Sorry, I did not mention that I set `batchSize` to 10000 already. It seems that mongo has to use `getmore` because of the 16MB BSON limit. My documents are 53 KB on average, which is 530 MB when querying for 10000 documents. 530/16 = ~ 33 and that is the same amount of operations executed for the query (1 query op and 32 getmore ops). So I guess what I'm experiencing is the time needed to transport (mongo server and app both on localhost) and deserialize 530 MB of documents to the application.

Comment: yeah, transferring and deserialization of a large quantity of docs is not the way to go.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ Yes, the app shows 10000 or even more results. It builds a diagram that shows information about each document. Each document has an array that embeds hundreds of smaller objects that each only have 3 fields. It uses the information of one of these embedded documents to position the parent document inside the diagram. So I guess another option would be to select which of these embedded documents should be returned with the result to decrease the data that has to be transferred. So using `unwind`, `match` and `group` and see if that is better.